# Can you identify this rose?

Tags: identification

I'm trying to identify this rose. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: This image is the same as one on the Spruce.com website, originally posted on Pinterest, where its described as a 'hardy miniature rose'. Unhelpfully, neither site includes the name of that particular variety, so other than being able to say its a hardy miniature rose, I don't recognise the variety either.

Answer (score -1):

shrub, maybe Rugosa? Looks like one I had growing out front of my house, but didn't do well with the lack of full sun in that area...